# Using Mysql WHERE IN clause in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have the following mysql query. Could you please tell me how to write the same query in Codeigniter's way ?

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
         WHERE trans_id IN ( SELECT trans_id FROM myTable WHERE code='B') 
         AND code!='B'
```

Comment: did you use subquery in codeigniter as i posted

Comment: Yes, I have managed to use it successfully few minutes ago.. :) Thanks :)

Comment: @raheelshan. Would you please check this post. http://stackoverflow.com/q/11045611/1209690 Thanks :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use sub query way of codeigniter to do this for this purpose you will have to hack codeigniter. like this
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php
Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now subquery writing in available
And now here is your query with active record

```
$this->db->select('trans_id');
$this->db->from('myTable');
$this->db->where('code','B');
$subQuery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();
// And now your main query
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->where_in("$subQuery");
$this->db->where('code !=', 'B');
$this->db->get('myTable');
```

And the thing is done. Cheers!!!
Note : While using sub queries you must use

```
$this->db->from('myTable')
```

instead of

```
$this->db->get('myTable')
```

which runs the query.
Watch this too

[How can I rewrite this SQL into CodeIgniter's Active Records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502778/how-can-i-rewrite-this-sql-into-codeigniters-active-records/10546395#10546395)

Note : In Codeigntier 3 these functions are already public so you do not need to hack them.

Answer (score 17):

```
$data = $this->db->get_where('columnname',array('code' => 'B'));
$this->db->where_in('columnname',$data);
$this->db->where('code !=','B');
$query =  $this->db->get();
return $query->result_array();
```

Answer (score 7):

Try this one:

```
$this->db->select("*");
$this->db->where_in("(SELECT trans_id FROM myTable WHERE code = 'B')");
$this->db->where('code !=', 'B');
$this->db->get('myTable');
```

Note: $this->db->select("*"); is optional when you are selecting all columns from table

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
return $this->db->query("
     SELECT * FROM myTable 
     WHERE trans_id IN ( SELECT trans_id FROM myTable WHERE code='B') 
     AND code!='B'
     ")->result_array();
```

Is not active record but is codeigniter's way http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/examples.html
see Standard Query With Multiple Results (Array Version) section

Answer (score 0):

you can use a simpler approach, while still using active record

```
$this->db->select("a.trans_id ,a.number, a.name, a.phone")
$this->db->from("Name_Of_Your_Table a");
$subQueryIn = "SELECT trans_id FROM Another_Table";
$this->db->where("a.trans_id in ($subQueryIn)",NULL);
```