# Mysql: Subtracting values based on two queries

Tags: mysql

I have the following two queries.

```
SELECT 
    account_name,SUM(amount) AS AMOUNT1 
FROM 
    entries 
LEFT JOIN 
    accounts ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
WHERE 
    side = 'D' AND op_balance_dc = 'D'
GROUP BY 
    accounts.id
```

Here's the result of the query:

[Query1](http://i49.tinypic.com/1zxqng7.png)

```
SELECT 
    account_name,SUM(amount) AS AMOUNT2 
FROM 
    entries 
LEFT JOIN 
    accounts ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
WHERE 
    side = 'C' AND op_balance_dc = 'D'
GROUP BY 
    accounts.id
```

Here's the result of the second query

[Query2](http://i50.tinypic.com/2zoy9a9.png)

I am not trying to display the results of the above two queries, what I am trying to achieve is get the account_name, AMOUNT1 and AMOUNT2 FROM the above queries and then subtract Amount2 FROM AMOUNT1- and then add a value from my table's column.

Example:

```
(AMOUNT1-AMOUNT2)+op_balance  //here op_balance is my column name
```

and then display the `account_name` and `(AMOUNT1-AMOUNT2)+op_balance`

Could you please help me with this query?

Thanks :)

Please let me know if you need anymore information.:)

### Edited

Here's the structure of my tables:

- Table Name: [accounts](http://i48.tinypic.com/2ew1hfc.png)
- Table Name: [entries](http://i49.tinypic.com/142y24l.png)

Thanks :)

### Edit2

Table Name: entries (Case-1)

```
  id    trans_id   accounts_id    amount    side
   1      1       12               1000      D
   2      1        1               1000      C
   7      4        1              14000      D
   8      4        2              14000      C
```

Table Name: entries  (Case-2)

```
  id    trans_id   accounts_id  amount        side
  1           1       12          1000       D
  2           1        1          1000       C
```

Your code will work for the case-1 but not for case-2. You used `lentries.accounts_id = entries.accounts_id` in your code and that is why since there's no multiple values for the same `accounts_id` in the table to join and your code is not counting the values in case-2.

But I am trying to get all the data. Thanks :)

Comment: You can do this with a JOIN but to write the SQL we need to know in which table holds which column.

Comment: Can you post your table structure?

Comment: can you post your data structure on http://sqlfiddle.com/ so that i can try what you need

Comment: i have created a query please test it to see how its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the EDITED QUERY for all accounts

```
select
  a.id,
  a.account_name,
  a.op_balance,
  ifnull(e.AMOUNT1,0) as Amount1,
  ifnull(l.AMOUNT2,0) as Amount2,
  ((ifnull(SUM(e.AMOUNT1),0)-ifnull(l.AMOUNT2,0))+a.op_balance) as Balance
from accounts a
  left join (SELECT
               accounts_id,
               SUM(amount)     AS AMOUNT1
             FROM entries
               LEFT JOIN accounts
                 ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
             WHERE entries.side = 'D'
                 AND accounts.op_balance_dc = 'D'
             GROUP BY accounts.id) as e
    on e.accounts_id = a.id
  left join (SELECT
               accounts_id,
               SUM(amount)     AS AMOUNT2
             FROM entries
               LEFT JOIN accounts
                 ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
             WHERE side = 'C'
                 AND op_balance_dc = 'D'
             GROUP BY accounts.id) as l
    on l.accounts_id = a.id
group by a.id
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried your code, but its not working perfectly. Because of `on lentries.accounts_id = entries.accounts_id` in your code I am not getting all the values, I suppose. In the table entries I may have only one data with one `accounts_id` and that is why you code is not counting the single data. Here's my table structure: http://jsbin.com/uzulip/2/edit

Comment: and what exactly do you want??

Comment: Excellent Work Man. Working perfectly :)

Comment: when you are posting your question make sure your requirements are clear it has happened before you ask for edits after our first answer and @Zane Bien answer is correct according to your questions and my answer is correct for youe edited part

Comment: Sorry :(  , Will do next time.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
    a.account_name,
    a.AMOUNT1,
    b.AMOUNT2,
    (a.AMOUNT1 - COALESCE(b.AMOUNT2, 0)) + a.op_balance AS calculated
FROM
    (
        SELECT accounts.id, account_name, SUM(amount) AS AMOUNT1, op_balance
        FROM entries 
        LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
        WHERE side='D' AND op_balance_dc='D'
        GROUP BY accounts.id
    ) a
LEFT JOIN
    (
        SELECT accounts.id, SUM(amount) AS AMOUNT2 FROM entries 
        LEFT JOIN accounts ON accounts.id = entries.accounts_id
        WHERE side='C' AND op_balance_dc='D'
        GROUP BY accounts.id
    ) b ON a.id = b.id
GROUP BY
    a.id
```

Comment: Hi, I just found that because of `b ON a.id = b.id` in your code, if I have only single value in my table `entries`, it doesn't show any data.