# CodeIgniter Active Record 'like' ignoring 'where'

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

riting a very simple search using like and have an option to omit options, however I find the like statement is making query ignore the where statement

```
$this->db->like('LOWER(location) OR LOWER(name)', strtolower($term));
$this->db->where('stage', 1);
$this->db->order_by("name", "asc"); 
$query = $this->db->get($this->user_table);
return $query->result();
```

Example of what the above produces with $term = "dublin";

```
SELECT * FROM (`users`) WHERE `stage` = 1 AND LOWER(location) OR LOWER(name) LIKE '%dublin%' ORDER BY `name` asc"
```

It still returns rows where 'stage' is not equal to 1.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: look at this answer an alternative http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter/11031431#11031431

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$term = strtolower($term);
$this->db->where("(LOWER(location) LIKE '%{$term}%' OR LOWER(name) LIKE '%{$term}%')");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT id_alimento, nombre, unidad, energia_kcal FROM catalogo_alimentos WHERE LOWER(nombre) LIKE '%".$this->db->escape_like_str($search)."%'");
if($query != false){
  if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
    return $query->result();
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some information here about why this is an answer.

Answer (score -1):

Substitute this for the query

```
$term = strtolower($term);
$this->db->where("stage= 1 AND (LOWER(location) LIKE '%{$term}%' OR LOWER(name) LIKE '%{$term}%')");
```

Comment: Please don't give code-only answers. Explain what your code does, and how does it fulfill OPs requirements.