# why codeigniter active record 'LIKE' not work in update query?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

```
$array=array(
 'amount'=>$this->input->post('netamt'),
 'trandate'=>$billdate,
 'crcode'=>$this->input->post('rcode')
  );
  $this->db->where('voucher',$this->input->post('billno'));
  $this->db->like('code','16','after');
  $this->db->update('tranachst',$array);
```

when display this query using 
    echo $this->db->last_query();

```
UPDATE `tranachst` SET `amount` = '717360', `trandate` = '2015-07-15', `crcode` = '311001' WHERE `voucher` = '15020'
```

here like query not working , why ?

Comment: 'like' does not effect update query in codeigniter,so it is not working with update query

Comment: its working fine at my system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please Try This --

My Exmaple --

```
$this->db->where('faq_id', $id);
$this->db->where('question LIKE ', '%do%'); 
$this->db->update('admin_faqs', $data);
```

Your Example --

```
$array=array(
 'amount'=>$this->input->post('netamt'),
 'trandate'=>$billdate,
 'crcode'=>$this->input->post('rcode')
  );
  $this->db->where('voucher',$this->input->post('billno'));
  $this->db->where('code LIKE ', '16%'); 
  $this->db->update('tranachst',$array);
```

In this code you don`t need to use after, before parameter please try this..

Answer (score 0):

Some people have the same question, and until now i don't know why. but clearly CI didn't support active record like above.

you can use `$this->db->query()` or

```
function index(){
    $this->load->database();
    $data=array(
        'userlogin'=>'test'
    );
    $this->db->where('userlogin','xx');
    $this->db->where("email like 'xx'");
    $q=$this->db->update('master_user',$data);

}
```

something like that work too.
the same question : [CodeIgniter Active Record 'like' ignoring 'where'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11187831/codeigniter-active-record-like-ignoring-where)