# codeigniter change complex query into active record

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a codeigniter app.

My active record syntax works perfectly and is:

```
  function get_as_09($q){
    $this->db->select('m3');
    $this->db->where('ProductCode', $q);
    $query = $this->db->get('ProductList');
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['m3'])); //build an array
       }
       return $row_set;
    }
  }
```

This is effectively

```
select 'm3' from 'ProductList' where ProductCode='$1'
```

What I need to do is convert the below query into an active record type query and return it to the controller as per above active record syntax:

```
select length from
(SELECT  
      [Length]
      ,CONCAT(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE([ProductCode],concat(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'')) as options
  FROM [dbo].[dbo].[ProductList]) as p
  where options='25100cr' order by length
```

I picture something like below but this does not work.

```
$this->db->select(length);
$this->db->from(SELECT  [Length],CONCAT(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE[ProductCode],concat(([width]*1000),([thickness]*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'')) as options
      FROM [dbo].[dbo].[ProductList]);
$this->db->where(options, $q);
$this->db->order(length, desc);
```

Help appreciated as always. Thanks again.

Comment: Why don't you just execute your sql query ? 
`$this->db->query($sql)`

Comment: @Brewal, not open to injection or any other security vulnerabilities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use sub query way of codeigniter to do this for this purpose you will have to hack codeigniter. like this
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

Now subquery writing in available And now here is your query with active record

```
$select =   array(
                'Length'
                'CONCAT(([width]*1000)',
                'thickness * 1000',
                'REPLACE(ProductCode, concat((width*1000),(thickness*1000),REPLACE((convert(varchar,convert(decimal(8,1),length))),'.','')),'')) as options'
);
$this->db->select($select);
$this->db->from('ProductList');

$Subquery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();

$this->db->select('length');
$this->db->from("($Subquery)");
$this->db->where('options','25100cr');
$this->db->order_by('length');
```

And the thing is done. Cheers!!!
Note : While using sub queries you must use

```
$this->db->from('myTable')
```

instead of

```
$this->db->get('myTable')
```

which runs the query.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter/11031431#11031431)

Comment: Hi raheel, how do set this entire query = $q so I can do `  $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    if($query->num_rows > 0){
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $row){
            $row_set[] = htmlentities(stripslashes($row['length'])); //build an array
       }
       return $row_set;
    }
  }`

Comment: instead of ` $query=$this->db->query($sql)` use ` $query=$this->db->get()` and than your if condition and so on

Comment: For what it's worth, the query builder is not designed for hacky things like this. If you need subqueries and whatnot, you should be writing the queries manually. You can use [query bindings](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/queries.html) to make sure your data is escaped (proper validation before hand is also recommended).