# Implementing SQL in codeignites active record

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

How can i convert this sql to codeigniters active record format

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM(
SELECT DISTINCT component
FROM `multiple_sample_assay_abc`
WHERE labref = 'NDQA201303001'
)x
```

I have tried this function but it has sql error

```
 function getAssayMultipleCount($labref){
        $this->db->count_all('*');
        $this->db->from();
        $this->db->distinct('component');
        $this->db->from('multiple_sample_assay_abc');
        $this->db->where('labref',$labref);
        $query=  $this->db->get();
        return $result=$query->result();
        //print_r($result);
    }
```

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter/11031431#11031431) might help

Answer (score 0):

you are using 2 $this->db->from() statements.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function getAssayMultipleCount($labref){
    $this->db->distinct('component');
    $this->db->from('multiple_sample_assay_abc');
    $this->db->where('labref',$labref);
    $query=  $this->db->get();
    $result=$query->result();
    return count($result);
    //print_r($result);
}
```

You can just count the no of elements after the query is executed. You don't have to use sub query for this

Comment: also num_rows() could be directly used on the query object