# How to reset current query in CI active record?

Tags: activerecord, codeigniter-2

Is it possible to reset a query created with `Codeigniter ActiveRecord`? For example a creating some query and need to get some id for this query from db, so i need to do a custom small query in other method, but in query container already exists some parts of query from previous query - is is possible to clear it?

Comment: See http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html#caching

Comment: take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter/11031431#11031431)