# How to search data using multiple where Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter

I have some issue when I want to search some data from my database using Codeigniter. I want to select data where the level is 0 and 3 with status 1

```
    tb_user_data :  
         ----------------------------------
        | username | name | level | status |
         ----------------------------------
        | abb      | ab   | 0     | 1      |
        | abc      | aa   | 1     | 1      |
        | aac      | bb   | 2     | 1      |
        | acc      | cc   | 3     | 1      |
         ----------------------------------

script select data 

$data["adm"] = $this->db->where("level", "0")
                        ->or_where("level", "3")
                        ->where("status", "1")
                        ->get('tb_user_data')->result_array();
```

when I try to search it by the name, the script doesn't working. Or I got some wrong script or anything else?

thank you

Comment: doesn't work is the WORST thing a programmer should say to a other programmer.. the code doesn't include the name search .. try adding `andWhere("name", [name])`

Comment: just write the syntax inline in one function `where('(a or b) and c')`

Comment: you can ->where_in clause in codeigniter. see below link it will be helpful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter

Comment: By the way you can debug your sql before see the result using `$this->db->last_query();`

Comment: thank you guys, problem solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$data["adm"] = $this->db->where_in('level', array('0','3'))
                        ->where("status", "1")
                        ->get('tb_user_data')->result_array();
```

Comment: Welcome @ImamNur. Accept as answer if it helps you. :)