# How can I Compare multiple ids in where condition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have multiple ids in my `$temp` like(7,8,9) and I want to compare there ids in my  where condition like `$this->db->where_in('c.mr_no',$temp);` but it compare only first id

I am trying like this:

**Controller:**

```
public function printCollectionRecPage()
{
    $this->load->view('template/header');
    $this->load->view('template/sidebar');

    $temp    =($_GET['id']); 
    $data    = array();

    $data['collnR'] = $this->PayRecAllModel->printCollectionRecPage($temp);

    $this->load->view('crossing/payment_rec_allocation/printCollectionRecovery',$data);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
}
```

**Model:**

```
public function printCollectionRecPage($temp)
{
    $this->db->select('c.*,payment_rec_allocn.*');
    $this->db->from('crossing_cash_memo c');
    $this->db->join('payment_rec_allocn', 'payment_rec_allocn.mr_no = c.mr_no');
    $this->db->where('c.total !=','0');
    $this->db->where('c.mr_no',$temp);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

I want to compare all 3 ids in where condition.

Comment: `$this->db->where_in('c.mr_no',$temp);` . Mkae sure `$temp = array(7,8,9);`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023318/using-mysql-where-in-clause-in-codeigniter

Comment: @AnantSingh---AlivetoDie I use where_in  `$this->db->where_in('c.mr_no',$temp);` but  still it compare only first id(7)

Comment: What's the value of `$temp`? It looks like it's just `$_GET['id']`.

Comment: @showdev In model `$temp` have 3 ids(7,8,9)

Comment: Is it an array?

Comment: @showdev no this is not array

Comment: Note the [comment from Anant Singh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57289193/how-can-i-compare-multiple-ids-in-where-condition#comment101072976_57289193). CodeIgniter's [`where_in`](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in) accepts an "[a]rray of target values".

Comment: @farhantechno  then what it is? is it a string like  `$temp ="7,8,9"`?

Comment: @showdev i used this `$temp = array(7,8,9)` in `$this->db->where_in('c.mr_no',array(7,8,9));` its works but my ids are dynamic so I am storing it in a variable `$temp` how I can compare with variable `$temp`

Comment: @farhantechno  how's you are storing them? show that code to us.

Comment: @farhantechno. You can find the length of array and loop it though 'where' condition.

Comment: There's also an [`or_where`](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=or_where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::or_where) function that you could use to join multiple instances by `OR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are receiving an string from **$_GET** and hence the comparisions are not working as expected.

Change this

```
$this->db->where('c.mr_no',$temp);
```

to

```
$temp = explode(",", $temp);
$this->db->where_in('c.mr_no',$temp);
```

and then try. **Where_in** excepts the parameter to be an array.