# Codeigniter - Calling a model method within same model is buggy

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, query-builder

I am trying to call a model method within same model and its not working as intended. Here is my class with two methods which do not work

```
class mymodel extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->tablea = 'tablea';
        $this->tableb = 'tableb';
    }

    public function saveData($data){
        $dataCopy['revisionkey'] = $this->getRevisionKey($data['id']);
        //check and condition revision key to be int with +1 from last one
        $this->db->insert($this->tableb, $dataCopy);
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        return $this->db->update($this->user_table, $data) ? true : false;
    }

    public function getRevisionKey($id){
        $this->db->select($this->revision_tablea.'.revisions_number as revisions_number')
            ->from($this->revision_tablea)
            ->where($this->revision_tablea.'.id', $id)
            ->order_by($this->revision_table.'.revisions_number', 'asc')
            ->limit(1);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row_array();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now method `getRevisionKey()` should produce a query like following

```
SELECT `tableb`.`revisions_number` as revisions_number FROM (`tableb`) WHERE `tableb`.`id` = '26' ORDER BY `tableb`.`revisions_number` asc LIMIT 1
```

but it produces a query like following

```
SELECT `tableb`.`revisions_number` as revisions_number FROM (`tableb`) WHERE `id` = '26' AND `tableb`.`id` = '26' ORDER BY `tableb`.`revisions_number` asc LIMIT 1
```

This of course is due to same method being called within the model, this method works fine if used outside of model. Any solution to this problem?

**EDIT**
Rewriting the `getRevisionKey()` fixes this. Here is the new version

```
    public function getRevisionKey($id){
        $sqlQuery = $this->db->select($this->revision_tablea.'.revisions_number as revisions_number')
            ->from($this->revision_tablea)
            ->order_by($this->revision_table.'.revisions_number', 'asc')
            ->limit(1);
        $query = $sqlQuery->where($this->revision_tablea.'.id', $id)->get();
        if ($query->num_rows() > 0){
            return $query->row_array();
        }else{
            return 0;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you using `getRevisionKey()` externally? I mean from any controller?

Comment: In my opinion the problem is the `$this->db->where('id', $id);` in the method above, seems to me like it's adding the extra parameter in addition to the function below which is correct.

Comment: @Aniket I am using this in a controller and as expected it works fine.

Comment: @MarioPeshev, you are correct. Is there any solution to this problem? Of course I can do some work around but the original problem remains.

Comment: I'm guessing you've made some modifications before posting here? Because in the `getRevisionKey` you call `$this->revision_tablea` but you define `$this->tablea` and you have `order_by($this->revision_table.` without A or B at the end. What I'm saying is, I don't see anything wrong, but did you perhaps cut out some parts that could be causing it?

Comment: @Kumar do you really need this where line in the method above? What happens if you comment it out?

Comment: @danneth, oh yes, I didn't want to post the actual code. But the problem is regardless of my code. In `saveData()` I am trying to use 'getRevisionKey()' and both have `where`clause which I think is the way CI uses `$this->db` object.

Comment: @MarioPeshev I need that `where`, I guess problem can be reproduced easily with similar use cases.

Comment: The difference between both queries that you posted is only the id = 26 verification which comes from this where. If you don't need it here, you should omit it or wrap it with some appropriate if's depending on your cases :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple hack that will give you exactly where you are making a mistake.
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

And save it. Before running the function i mean calling

```
$this->db->get() // Use $this->db->from() instead
```

use

```
$query = $this->db->_compile_select()
```

and echo $query;

These two functions also help in subquery in codeigniter active record.
[How can I rewrite this SQL into CodeIgniter's Active Records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502778/how-can-i-rewrite-this-sql-into-codeigniters-active-records/10546395#10546395)

Comment: CI 3.0 has made all compile methods public. Very useful for debugging.