# iplementing sql query in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

```
SELECT * FROM abc
WHERE xyz LIKE $x OR xyz LIKE $y OR xyz LIKE $z
ORDER BY ((xyz LIKE $x) + (xyz LIKE $y) + (xyz LIKE $z)) DESC
```

I am able to write the query for pretty much `ordey by asd desc` but how to write this complex query in codeigniter?

Comment: see my answer this will help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502778/how-can-i-rewrite-this-sql-into-codeigniters-active-records/10546395#10546395

Answer (score 0):

You can write it in plain sql like you have it and execute it with the `db->query` method.

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM abc
WHERE xyz LIKE ? OR xyz LIKE ? OR xyz LIKE ?
ORDER BY ((xyz LIKE ?) + (xyz LIKE ?) + (xyz LIKE ?)) DESC'

$this->db->query($sql, array($x, $y, $z, $x, $y, $z));
```

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html query bindings explains the `?`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should check [ActiveRecord](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html):

```
$this->db->
   from("abc")->
   or_like("xyz",$x)->
   or_like(...)->
   order_by(...);
$result = $this->db->result_array();
```