# Codeigniter JOIN (SELECT query

Tags: codeigniter

It is possible to generate the following query by CI Query Builder class ?

```
SELECT name 
       FROM table1 t1 
                   JOIN 
                     (SELECT ID FROM table2 ORDER BY id LIMIT 5) t2 
                   ON t2.id=t1.t2_id 
       WHERE t1.id>5
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Well there are a couple of ways of doing it. One way is here which is a hack.

[How can I rewrite this SQL into CodeIgniter's Active Records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502778/how-can-i-rewrite-this-sql-into-codeigniters-active-records/10546395#10546395)

This other way is very simple.

```
$this->db
        ->select('ID')
        ->from('table2')
        ->order_by('id')
        ->limit('5');   

$subquery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select(); 

$query  =       $this->db
                    ->select('t1.name')
                    ->from('table1 t1 ')
                    ->join("($subquery)  t2","t2.id = t1.t2_id")
                    ->get('table1 t1');
```

Some point about it.
You are bound to use from clause in subqueries because get runs the query.
In codeigniter 2 _compile_select and _reset_select can not be accessed because they are protected methods.
You may have to remove the keyword before both methods in system/database/DB_active_rec.php

[This](http://heybigname.com/2009/09/18/using-code-igniters-active-record-class-to-create-subqueries/) article is useful too.

Comment: I asked for **CI Query Builder** not raw query, i can run raw query o'c,

Comment: Well i have added the links of two articles which you haven't even seen they tell exactly how to do it. One is my own answer. Care to have a look?

Comment: and why you placed the worse answer on this ? 2nd link looks good, may  be it is best way to do that

Comment: if you can't understand the answer it does not mean it is worse it has been implementation of the 2nd link.

Comment: implementation of 2nd link [here](http://codepad.org/KvCIQoEt) your sample is just simple query run...

Comment: yes, just after you fix  the answer, i can't accept the answer without it

Comment: thanks for notes, but I'm on CI3, it have `$this->db->get_compiled_select()` and `$this->db->reset_query()`

Answer (score 5):

in CI3, simply use the fourth parameters for escape

```
$this->db->from('table')
->join('SELECT id from table2 where something=%s) as T2'),'table.id=T2.id', 'LEFT',NULL)
->get()->row();
```

Don't forget to escape parameters in your subquery to avoid SQL Injection.

Comment: **by CI Query Builder class**

Answer (score 0):

this library can help you to use sub queries with query builder have look on the doc of this library

[sub query with query builder](https://github.com/NTICompass/CodeIgniter-Subqueries)

Comment: would be usefull if it was implemented as `group_start()`

Comment: well you can add this feature to this library and share with developer on github will be useful for other developers too

Comment: will do when I got a time for that and know CI more than now