# how can we join this two table results in to one

Tags: php, mysql, join, codeigniter-3

Here i want to to join this two query results in to one result 
the first query looks like this

```
   $this->db->select('bills.date as d_date,bill_details.agent_name,
   SUM(bill_details.profit) AS total_profit');
   $this->db->join('bill_details', 'bill_details.bill_id=bills.id','left'); 
   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) >=', $start_date);
   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) <=', $end_date); 
   $this->db->group_by('Date(bills.date)');
   $this->db->group_by('bills.customerid');
   $query1 = $this->db->get('bills')->result();
   return $query1;
```

the result looks like this

```
Name    Date          Purchase  
Ned     2019-07-26      210.60
```

the second query looks like this

```
    $this->db->select('assigned_result.date,assigned_result.user_id,SUM(assigned_result.total_price) AS t_price,SUM(assigned_result.total_dc) AS t_dc');
    $this->db->where('DATE(assigned_result.date) >=', $start_date);
    $this->db->where('DATE(assigned_result.date) <=', $end_date);

    $this->db->group_by('assigned_result.user_id');
    $query2 = $this->db->get('assigned_result')->result();
```

the second query result looks like this

```
Name    Date          winning
Ned     2019-07-26      120
```

Now i want to combine the queries like this

```
Name    Date          Purchase   winning 
Ned     2019-07-26      210.60         120
```

For getting this result i had joined the queries and return like this

```
$this->db->select('bills.date as d_date,bill_details.agent_name,
   SUM(bill_details.profit) AS total_profit,SUM(assigned_result.total_price) AS t_price,SUM(assigned_result.total_dc) AS t_dc');
   $this->db->join('bill_details', 'bill_details.bill_id=bills.id','left'); 
   $this->db->join('assigned_result', 'bills.id=assigned_result.bill_no', 'left');
   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) >=', $start_date);
   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) <=', $end_date); 
   $this->db->group_by('Date(bills.date)');
   $this->db->group_by('bills.customerid');
   $query1 = $this->db->get('bills')->result();
   return $query1;
```

but am getting result like this

```
Name    Date          Purchase  winning
Ned     2019-07-26      226      160
```

`purchase amount` is getting wrongly.

Comment: The problem is the joining of assigned_result table. An extra value is getting in  total_profit while joining

Comment: Any idea anybody have

Comment: It seems you have a mistake in first sql query, here `$this->db->join('bills', 'bill_details.bill_id=bills.id','left'); `. Otherwise, I could help you to make the last query resultable.

Comment: @AksenP  still am getting same...

Comment: @AksenP i had tried a lot but still am not getting

Comment: show the first table rows `where Name = 'Ned'`, without `SUM()`, do it in your database sql editor. The second step - check your `join`, because you're joining `bills` with `bills`, you see? The third step - you're showing the second query result not according to your `select`'ed columns as you've wrote in query.

Comment: no am not joining `bills` with `bills` table.am joining `bills` with `bill_details` and `assigned_result` table

Comment: check your code near `$query1`... Otherwise, do what I ask, cause it's to hard identify what means `t_price` or `t_dc`  columns aliases according to your result view... you're joining `$this->db->join('` **bills** `', 'bill_details.bill_id=bills.id','left');` and after doing `$this->db->get('` **bills** `')->result();`.

Comment: there is no line `$this->db->join(' bills ', 'bill_details.bill_id=bills.id','left');` like this in my query

Comment: [img1](https://imgur.com/MJH3F8V) and [img2](https://imgur.com/NW7xFVk). And now you will say to me the same? Your data is unclear. Please, make columns more understandable. I mean - what column of these are equal to `winning`?

Comment: sorry that was mistakenly typed and changed that code..Now can you please check that

Comment: `winning` equal to the sum of  `t_price` and `t_dc`

Answer (score 0):

Accroding to your `SQL Editor` data next query is for you:

```
select 
   B.user_id, 
   B.agent_name, 
   sum(B.profit),
   C2.tprice, 
   C2.tdc 
from B 
      join A on A.id = B.bill_id and A.customerid = B.user_id
 left join ( select 
                  C.user_id, 
                  C.data_id, 
                  C.bill_no, 
                  sum(C.total_price) tprice, 
                  sum(C.total_dc) tdc from C) C2 on C2.data_id = B.id and C2.user_id = B.user_id 
group by B.user_id;
```

**PHP:** ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251358/codeigniter-join-select-query))

```
    $this->db->select('DATE(bills.date) as d_date,
                      bill_details.user_id,
                      bill_details.agent_name,
                      SUM(bill_details.profit) AS total_profit,
                      C2.tprice AS t_price,
                      C2.tdc AS t_dc');

   $this->db->join('bills', 'bills.id = bill_details.bill_id and bills.customerid = bill_details.user_id','left');
   $this->db->join('(select 
                assigned_result.user_id, 
                assigned_result.data_id, 
                assigned_result.bill_no, 
                sum(assigned_result.total_price) tprice, 
                sum(assigned_result.total_dc) tdc from assigned_result) as C2','C2.data_id = bill_details.id and C2.user_id = bill_details.user_id', 'LEFT'); 

   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) >=', $start_date);
   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) <=', $end_date); 

   $this->db->group_by('bill_details.user_id)'); 

   $query1 = $this->db->get('bill_details')->result();
   return $query1;
```

or

```
    $this->db->select('assigned_result.user_id, 
                assigned_result.data_id, 
                assigned_result.bill_no, 
                sum(assigned_result.total_price) tprice, 
                sum(assigned_result.total_dc) tdc')
            ->from('assigned_result');   

    $subquery = $this->db->_compile_select();
    $this->db->_reset_select();  

    $this->db->select('DATE(bills.date) as d_date,
                      bill_details.user_id,
                      bill_details.agent_name,
                      SUM(bill_details.profit) AS total_profit,
                      C2.tprice AS t_price,
                      C2.tdc AS t_dc');

   $this->db->join('bills', 'bills.id = bill_details.bill_id and bills.customerid = bill_details.user_id','left');
   $this->db->join("($subquery) C2",'C2.data_id = bill_details.id and C2.user_id = bill_details.user_id', 'LEFT'); 

   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) >=', $start_date);
   $this->db->where('DATE(bills.date) <=', $end_date); 

   $this->db->group_by('bill_details.user_id)'); 

   $query1 = $this->db->get('bill_details')->result();
   return $query1;
```

Comment: No still i got same result..here is my data collection and i changed table names `bills ` as `A` and `bill_details` as `B` and `assigned_result` as `C`http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c85a910/3

Comment: @user_777, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c85a910/39 Now I'll help you to make a new php query.

Comment: thankyou for helping in your first query i got the `total_profit` value  but the `t_price` and `t_dc` gets null

Comment: @user_777, try to find how to make a subquery, you need to create `C2 table` for joining, as you see in `SQL Editor`, read the reference and try to get it. You see that it depends of CodeIgniter version and core files.